# $\psi_1$-Orlicz norm of a product of two Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution, orlicz-spaces

Is there a direct formula or a bound for the following Orlicz norm: $\|\xi \eta\|_{\psi_1}$, where $\xi, \eta \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$ are standard normal random variables, $\psi_1(x) = e^x - 1$?

One way to bound this quantity would be $\|\xi \eta\|_{\psi_1} \leqslant \|\xi\|_{\psi_2} \|\eta\|_{\psi_2}$, and then compute the $\psi_2$-norm of a standard normal variable. Can this bound be improved? It gives the answer $8 / 3$.

A reminder:
$$
\|\xi\|_{\psi_1} = \inf \{t > 0 | \mathbb{E}\exp\{|\xi| / t\} \leqslant 2\}
$$

**EDIT:** It seems that the previous bound can indeed be improved. If one plots the approximate expectations, one can notice that the true value of the norm is below 2.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the definition of the Orlitz-norm $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\psi$ is correct? The right-hand side does not even depend on $\psi$.

Comment: @SmallDeviation yes, it is correct, here $\psi_1(x) = e^{x} - 1$. In general, $\|\xi\|_{\psi} = \inf \{t > 0 | \mathbb{E}\psi(|\xi| / t) \leqslant 1\}$

Comment: Then you should include the definition of $\psi_1$ in your post. Otherwise it is impossible for us to know what $\psi_1$ is.

Comment: I don't know if there is a way to get anything other than a numeric solution, which gives you something like $t = 1.3725$

Comment: I am assuming you did figure out the definite integral?

Comment: @LSK21, which definite integral are you talking about? Thanks for the numeric solution!

Comment: I wrote up what I know in an answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

In order to calculate the sub-exponential norm, define
$$ f(t) := \mathbb{E}[\exp(|\xi|/t)] $$
for $t > 0$. Then, we can simplify $f$ as follows by recalling the density of the Gaussian distribution:
\begin{equation*}
f(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp(\frac{|z|}{t}) \exp(-\frac{z^2}{2}) dz
\end{equation*}
Now, I admit I used an [integral calculator](https://www.integral-calculator.com) when I was first interested in this and plugged in the right side to get
$$ f(t) = \exp(\frac{1}{2t^2}) \left( \text{erf}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}t}) + 1 \right) $$
where *erf* denotes the [Gaussian error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).
(If you are interested in the steps, I can try and do the calculation again by hand, let me know in the comments)

Since $f$ is decreasing on $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$, we can now simply set the right side equal to $2$ in order to get the sub-exponential norm, which I did using Geogebra to get the approximate value I mentioned above (1.3725).

Note that the same procedure can be done for the sub-gaussian norm, which gives you $\sqrt{8/3}$ for the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! However, I think that the integral should be different. As we are calculating the norm of the product of two rvs, instead of $\xi$ we put not a standard normal rv, but a product of two standard normal random variables. Then the integral becomes more complex

Comment: Ah of course, I was thinking of just a single r.v.

Comment: You could try using the calculator I linked, but I suspect the modified Bessel function is a bit too much for it